# Do I need \leavevmode for centering figures?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I have an image I'd like horizontally centered on the page.  Currently, I'm using the following code (which does work) under pdflatex:

```
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{PicName}
\end{center}
\caption{Some kind of sane Caption}
\label{fig:picref}
\end{figure}
```

The references I've found on the ineternet are pretty much split 50-50 on whether the \leavevmode is required there or not.  But, I can't find anything that says point blank what it's for.

So, my two-part question: what exactly does \leavevmode do, and do I need it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\leavevmode` is defined this way:

```
\def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}
```

source2e.pdf comments:

> `\leavevmode`  begins a paragraph, if necessary.

I would say, this is not necessary, so you don't need `\leavevmode`. You could further consider to use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` because the latter produces additional vertical space, because it's actually a list environment.

Another source mentioning that it obviously had been used as workaround resp. bugfix: [Centering of too wide figure](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~anup/homepage/UNIX/latex.html#toowidefigure).

In comparing references it may help to look at the dates and the context. I know such reports concerning inclusion of EPS files, which doesn't apply to pdfTeX.

Comment: I'd be a bit more definite: really _not_ needed. (I'm working on the paragraph model for LaTeX3 at the moment, and inserting random `\leavevmode` items will cause all sorts of trouble there!)

Comment: Perfect, that was just what I wanted to know, thanks.

Comment: And, for the record, after replacing the center environment with \centering and removing \leavevmode, I swear the document renders faster.

Comment: @Electrons: It might compile _slightly_ faster, but render? That seems unlikely.