# Wrapfigure apparently creating dummy space on a following page

Tags: spacing, graphics, wrapfigure

[image]The example below is a newsletter with two news items.

The first item has a wrapfigure to include a graphic. The second does not

But the resulting PDF (made with PDFLaTeX) has a blank area close to the as if the second item had a graphic too.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Sorry about the extensive preamble - that's direct from the full document (which has dozens of news items).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{graphicx}![enter image description here][2]
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pdfminorversion=5
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullView, colorlinks=true,
 pdfhighlight=/P,linkbordercolor=.9 1 1, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black,pdftex}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
% Different font in captions
\newcommand{\captionfonts}{\Large}
\makeatletter % Allow the use of @ in command names
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
\vskip\abovecaptionskip
\sbox\@tempboxa{{\captionfonts #2}}%
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
{\captionfonts #2\par}
\else
\hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
\fi
\vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother % Cancel the effect of \makeatletter

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[co, ce]{\thepage{}}
\fancyhead[le ro]{Demo newsleter pages}
\fancyfoot{}
\scalefont{1.5}









% Item 01
% =========================


\begingroup
\color{blue}
\subsection*{news item 1 heading}
\endgroup

\begin{wrapfigure}
{R}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{center}    
\includegraphics*[width=0.24\textwidth]{public-domain-image-01.jpg}
\caption{caption for item-01}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\href{http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/view-image.php?image=9353&picture=sunset-on-a-california-beach&large=1}{[source of public domain image]}


\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext






% Item 02
% =========================

\begingroup
\color{blue}
\subsection*{news item 2}
\endgroup

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` before `\href`

Comment: \leavevmode certainly looks good, thanks; why not upgrade your comment to an answer, and perhaps x-ref to this explanation a little more here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\href` doesn't start LR mode by itself. Due to how `wrapfigure` works (the details are rather technical), the appearance of `\href` in vertical mode blocks the reset mechanism of the special paragraph shape required for placing the figure. So the simple solution is

```
\leavevmode\href{...}{...}
```

See [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode) for some details about `\leavevmode`.