# White space in subsequent pages after wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

I have used `\begin{wrapfigure}` on one of my pages.

Subsequently, the same amount of space is left (as white space) on all other pages.

The code I've used (it's a `\documentclass{article}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[l]{
  \includegraphics[height=12pt,keepaspectratio]{FltOps}
}
\fancyfoot[r]{
  \includegraphics[height=12pt,keepaspectratio]{QantasLogo}
}

\begin{document}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/Bob/Desktop/Internship report figures/} }

\section*{Executive Summary}

\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\section{About Qantas}

\subsection*{History}
Qantas was formally esthablished on 16 November 1920 in Brisbane, Queensland, Australia.  Currently it is the oldest continuously operated airline in the world. However, the story of the company officially called \textit{Queensland And Notheren Territories Aerial Services} began about a year earlier when the Federal Goverment offered a prize of 10,000 pounds for the first Australians to fly from England to Australia within 30 days. Former Australian Flying Corps officers W. Hudson Fysh and Paul McGinness, who served in Palestine on Bristol fighters during WWI, enlisted for the race. \\
Unfortunately their intended financier passed away before a suitable aircraft could be found. After a meeting with Fergus McMaster, Fysh and McGinness easily convinced him of their plans to set up an air service for the remote areas of the still densely populated Australia. Together with their former flight sergeant Arthur Baird as mechanic they travelled to Sydney to purchase their first Avro 504K. \\
These four men, who would remain connected to the company for years, first used their new airline for charter and joy-rides to raise capital. As soon as larger aircraft could be afforded regular mail and passengers services started, with the first scheduled flight being operated on 3 November 1922. Between 1926 and 1929 the newfounded company even started building its own aircraft, which makes it nowadays the only airline in the world to ever have done that. \\
As cooperation with the British Imperial Airways started, Qantas started its first overseas connections and on 17 april 1935 a four day flight from Brisbane to Singapore was made, which was the first official overseas flight by Qantas. This was part of what would become know as the Kangaroo-route. After a few years the airline decided to introduce Short C Class Empire flying boats, which would be used to run a trice-weekly service to England. \\
Qantas operated its international flight until the outbreak of WWII, since during the start of the war only domestic services were maintained. However in 1943 the British Air Ministry sought a plan together with BOAC, the former Imperial Airways, and Qantas to re-establish airial services between England and Australia. Flights on the Qantas-side would go from Perth, Australia, to Koggala Lake in Sri Lanka. This single hop over the Indian Ocean was with 5652 km the largest non-stop flight ever operated so far. The experience that Qantas had gained by transferring its Californian built Catalina aircraft would proove verey useful during these years. During the risky 271 crossings 648 passengers were flown while using celestial navigation because of the radio-silence that was required to escape enemy patrols.\\
In the years after the war Qantas quickly expanded its network with aircraft such as the Douglas DC3, DC4 and the Lockheed Constellation. After considerable debate the Australian Government decided in 1947 to buy all shares of Qantas while Hudson Fysh would remain Managing Director. The new destinations of the company now included far away places such as Hong Kong, Japan, South-Africa and from 1953 to North-America. \\
As the world entered the Jet age, Qantas would become the first airline outside the U.S. to fly the Boeing 707 in 1959 and a decade later, 1971, the Boeing 747 was introduced. Eventually, with the sale of the last 707 in 1979, the Qantas fleet consisted entirely of 747 aircraft until 1985. That year the Boeing 767 was introduced and in 1989, as part of a large fleet modernisation, the latest version of the 747 was taken into service: the 400 series. This type of aircraft is still being used until this day. \\
Eventually in 1992 the Australian Government announced that Qantas would be fully privatised, just after the airline had acquired its domestic competitor Australian Airlines. The now larger Qantas Group was able to sell a share of 25% to British Airways. As Qantas and Australian merged, the Group now consisted of Qantas and several regional susidiaries. In 2004 the new low-cost airline Jetstar was launched. While first only operating domestically, it nowadays also has international services and even special branches in Singapore and Japan under the banner of Jetstar Asia and Jetstar Japan respectively. On 20 October 2008 Qantas became the third airline in the world to operate the Airbus A380.     \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{QantasCorporate}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection*{Qantas Today}
Today the Qantas fleet consists of 146 aircraft and flies to 41 different destinations, both domestic and international. The Qantas Group, which employs 35,000 people, also consists of several susidiaries: Jetstart, QantasLink, Network Aviation, Express Freighters Australia, Qantas Freight and the New Zealand-based Jetconnect. The Group is part of Oneworld alliance, that serves over 850 different airports. \\
Since the start of the new millenium the more liberal airspace has not only given more opportunities to Qantas, but has also heavily increased the competition. On domestic flights Qantas mainly competes with Virgin Australia. However, on a international scale the competition becomes more complex. While Qantas is nowadays fully Australian owned, Virgin Australia has sold shares to Air New-Zealand, Singapore Airlines and Ethid Airways. While Qantas as a Group maintains to keep 65% of the domestic market, it only has 18% of the international market. \\
Being one of the strongest Australian brands, Qantas continues to have all its activities done within Australia, including its maintenance. Also, Qantas is until this day the oldest airline in the world that hasn't experienced any aircraft accident since the introduction of jet-powered aircraft. This record makes Qantas, along with several other factors, one of the safest airlines in the world.     \subsection*{Recent Developments and Future Strategy}

Qantas is in de middle of some big changes. First of all the airline is in the process of being split between Qantas Domestic and Qantas International. Within Australia Qantas is heavily competing with Virgin Australia as mentioned before. Last October there came a final stop to approaching the market agressively from both Qantas and Virgin by putting a lot of additional capacity in the market. While it is important for Qantas to retain a market-share of 65%, an increase in capacity from both sides resulted in overcapacity which naturally hurts both companies. \\
While things seems more quiet now domestically, there might be much more to come. Virgin Australia recently acquired budget airline Tiger Australia, formerly owned by Singapore Airways, and is meant to compete directly with Jetstar. Since Virgin previously had to keep an eye on both Qantas and Jetstar, in the near future the rival airline can completely focus on Qantas while Tiger will be taking on Jetstar. \\
As Virgin is linked internationally to Singapore, Etihad and Air New Zealand, and since there is a huge increase in air traffic from and to Asia, Qantas is turning its international division around in a few important ways. The most significant change is the recently initiated partnership with Emirates Airways. Qantas wants to lift its game to improve their product even more so it can match that of Emirates, it can link to Emirates' numerous European destinations and also increase passengers from and to the Middle East. Traditionally the famous Kangaroo route from Sydney to London hopped via Singapore, but that will be interchanged with Dubai. \\
With this important restructure on the Western side of the international network, Qantas will now be able to completely focus its attention to Asia. The flight schedule will be retimed from flights that previously would connect ideally with flights from Europe, to approaching Asia now directly with more convenient flight schedules and now treating it completely as a special market on its own. These changes took place in the last few months of the internship, so it is difficult to comment on results. However, they can be regarded as logical consequences of a changing world and market in which Qantas finding its place to continue its legacy. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please edit your question to be a complete small document that  shows the problem, you can `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so the graphic is not needed (it is replaced by a black rectangle) and add padding text enough to show the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks! Working on it, but I'm trying to replace my original text as well since it's rather confidential. Any idea how to replace the orignal text temporarily with lipsum lorem like with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`?

Comment: you could use `\usepackage{lipsum}` to generate enough junk text to fill your pages, see any number of examples on this site.

Comment: Yeah tried that already, but the new small, complete document didn't have the same problem as my original apparently. Found a similar question though but the answer isn't satisfactory. Unfortunately my 'reputation' doesn't allow me to comment on the answer or question. Link is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42374/wrapfigure-apparently-creating-dummy-space-on-a-following-page

Comment: well the issue there was using non latex command, at the start of a paragraph, so probably you have the same, `\hbox` or `\line`  or ... but basically without an example no one can help as wrapfig doesn't normally act as described.

Comment: You're absolutely right, so I've added the entire code of the first section. Should be enough to show the problem. I've looked into the issue of a non-latex command indeed. However I can't remember using such.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `wrapfigure` before the `\subsection`, but after it. *Don't* end paragraphs with ``\\``, but leaving a blank line in the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must put the `wrapfig` environment *after* the `\subsection` command and not before it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just to produce the example
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[l]{%
  \includegraphics[height=12pt,keepaspectratio]{FltOps}%
}
\fancyfoot[r]{%
  \includegraphics[height=12pt,keepaspectratio]{QantasLogo}%
}

\begin{document}
\graphicspath{{/Users/Bob/Desktop/Internship report figures/}}

\section{About Qantas}

\subsection*{History}

Qantas was formally esthablished on 16 November 1920 in Brisbane, Queensland, Australia.  
Currently it is the oldest continuously operated airline in the world. However, the story of 
the company officially called \textit{Queensland And Notheren Territories Aerial Services} 
began about a year earlier when the Federal Goverment offered a prize of 10,000 pounds for the 
first Australians to fly from England to Australia within 30 days. Former Australian Flying 
Corps officers W. Hudson Fysh and Paul McGinness, who served in Palestine on Bristol fighters 
during WWI, enlisted for the race.

Unfortunately their intended financier passed away before a suitable aircraft could be found. 
After a meeting with Fergus McMaster, Fysh and McGinness easily convinced him of their plans to 
set up an air service for the remote areas of the still densely populated Australia. Together 
with their former flight sergeant Arthur Baird as mechanic they travelled to Sydney to purchase 
their first Avro 504K.

These four men, who would remain connected to the company for years, first used their new 
airline for charter and joy-rides to raise capital. As soon as larger aircraft could be 
afforded regular mail and passengers services started, with the first scheduled flight being 
operated on 3 November 1922. Between 1926 and 1929 the newfounded company even started building 
its own aircraft, which makes it nowadays the only airline in the world to ever have done that.

As cooperation with the British Imperial Airways started, Qantas started its first overseas 
connections and on 17 april 1935 a four day flight from Brisbane to Singapore was made, which 
was the first official overseas flight by Qantas. This was part of what would become know as 
the Kangaroo-route. After a few years the airline decided to introduce Short C Class Empire 
flying boats, which would be used to run a trice-weekly service to England.

Qantas operated its international flight until the outbreak of WWII, since during the start of 
the war only domestic services were maintained. However in 1943 the British Air Ministry sought 
a plan together with BOAC, the former Imperial Airways, and Qantas to re-establish airial 
services between England and Australia. Flights on the Qantas-side would go from Perth, 
Australia, to Koggala Lake in Sri Lanka. This single hop over the Indian Ocean was with 5652 km 
the largest non-stop flight ever operated so far. The experience that Qantas had gained by 
transferring its Californian built Catalina aircraft would proove verey useful during these 
years. During the risky 271 crossings 648 passengers were flown while using celestial 
navigation because of the radio-silence that was required to escape enemy patrols.

In the years after the war Qantas quickly expanded its network with aircraft such as the 
Douglas DC3, DC4 and the Lockheed Constellation. After considerable debate the Australian 
Government decided in 1947 to buy all shares of Qantas while Hudson Fysh would remain Managing 
Director. The new destinations of the company now included far away places such as Hong Kong, 
Japan, South-Africa and from 1953 to North-America.

As the world entered the Jet age, Qantas would become the first airline outside the U.S. to fly 
the Boeing 707 in 1959 and a decade later, 1971, the Boeing 747 was introduced. Eventually, 
with the sale of the last 707 in 1979, the Qantas fleet consisted entirely of 747 aircraft 
until 1985. That year the Boeing 767 was introduced and in 1989, as part of a large fleet 
modernisation, the latest version of the 747 was taken into service: the 400 series. This type 
of aircraft is still being used until this day.

Eventually in 1992 the Australian Government announced that Qantas would be fully privatised, 
just after the airline had acquired its domestic competitor Australian Airlines. The now larger 
Qantas Group was able to sell a share of 25% to British Airways. As Qantas and Australian 
merged, the Group now consisted of Qantas and several regional susidiaries. In 2004 the new 
low-cost airline Jetstar was launched. While first only operating domestically, it nowadays 
also has international services and even special branches in Singapore and Japan under the 
banner of Jetstar Asia and Jetstar Japan respectively. On 20 October 2008 Qantas became the 
third airline in the world to operate the Airbus A380.

\subsection*{Qantas Today}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{QantasCorporate}
\end{wrapfigure}

Today the Qantas fleet consists of 146 aircraft and flies to 41 different destinations, both 
domestic and international. The Qantas Group, which employs 35,000 people, also consists of 
several susidiaries: Jetstart, QantasLink, Network Aviation, Express Freighters Australia, 
Qantas Freight and the New Zealand-based Jetconnect. The Group is part of Oneworld alliance, 
that serves over 850 different airports.

Since the start of the new millenium the more liberal airspace has not only given more 
opportunities to Qantas, but has also heavily increased the competition. On domestic flights 
Qantas mainly competes with Virgin Australia. However, on a international scale the competition 
becomes more complex. While Qantas is nowadays fully Australian owned, Virgin Australia has 
sold shares to Air New-Zealand, Singapore Airlines and Ethid Airways. While Qantas as a Group 
maintains to keep 65% of the domestic market, it only has 18% of the international market.

Being one of the strongest Australian brands, Qantas continues to have all its activities done 
within Australia, including its maintenance. Also, Qantas is until this day the oldest airline 
in the world that hasn't experienced any aircraft accident since the introduction of 
jet-powered aircraft. This record makes Qantas, along with several other factors, one of the 
safest airlines in the world.

\subsection*{Recent Developments and Future Strategy}

Qantas is in de middle of some big changes. First of all the airline is in the process of being 
split between Qantas Domestic and Qantas International. Within Australia Qantas is heavily 
competing with Virgin Australia as mentioned before. Last October there came a final stop to 
approaching the market agressively from both Qantas and Virgin by putting a lot of additional 
capacity in the market. While it is important for Qantas to retain a market-share of 65%, an 
increase in capacity from both sides resulted in overcapacity which naturally hurts both 
companies.

While things seems more quiet now domestically, there might be much more to come. Virgin 
Australia recently acquired budget airline Tiger Australia, formerly owned by Singapore 
Airways, and is meant to compete directly with Jetstar. Since Virgin previously had to keep an 
eye on both Qantas and Jetstar, in the near future the rival airline can completely focus on 
Qantas while Tiger will be taking on Jetstar.

As Virgin is linked internationally to Singapore, Etihad and Air New Zealand, and since there 
is a huge increase in air traffic from and to Asia, Qantas is turning its international 
division around in a few important ways. The most significant change is the recently initiated 
partnership with Emirates Airways. Qantas wants to lift its game to improve their product even 
more so it can match that of Emirates, it can link to Emirates' numerous European destinations 
and also increase passengers from and to the Middle East. Traditionally the famous Kangaroo 
route from Sydney to London hopped via Singapore, but that will be interchanged with Dubai.

With this important restructure on the Western side of the international network, Qantas will 
now be able to completely focus its attention to Asia. The flight schedule will be retimed from 
flights that previously would connect ideally with flights from Europe, to approaching Asia now 
directly with more convenient flight schedules and now treating it completely as a special 
market on its own. These changes took place in the last few months of the internship, so it is 
difficult to comment on results. However, they can be regarded as logical consequences of a 
changing world and market in which Qantas finding its place to continue its legacy.

\end{document}
```

***Notes.***

Don't end paragraphs with `\\`. It's wrong. Separate paragraphs with a blank line like I did in the example.

It's better to use `\centering` instead of a `center` environment in `wrapfigure`, as the latter adds vertical space.

Comment: Beautiful! Heaps thanks. I changed `center` to `\centering` indeed after reading on some other pages. Wasn't really sure about the `\\` or just a blank line, but thanks for correcting me in that as well!

Comment: @Robert Also watch out for spurious spaces in header and footer; check the `%` I added: a `\fancyfoot` instruction is similar to a `\newcommand` and end of lines in the argument count as spaces in the output. Have also a look at our [help page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Wow egreg! Learned so much new stuff from you! Thanks!

Comment: This problem has ruined today, It is now 3am and I can finally go to sleep. Thanks!!!

Comment: Placing the wrapfig after the \subsubsection (in my case) did indeed fix the issue. @egreg could you elaborate why? Should wrapfig's always be placed in the "innermost" section? What are the rules or guidance regarding wrapfig placement?