# Why `parskip` package makes margin notes misaligned?

Tags: incompatibility, marginpar, marginnote, parskip, cv

I have to merge two lengthy files, one of which is using the `marginnote` package and the other needs the `parskip` package. If I use them at the same time the command I use to label years in the margin, say `\years`, doesn't work as It should.

Following I am showing a code for example.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{marginnote,parskip}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[5][in]{\years{#2}\textsc{#3} #1 \emph{#4}, \textsc{#5}\\}
\begin{document}

\section*{Degrees}
\degree[on]{2017--2018}{Postdoctoral Research}{Computational Mathematics}{Somewhere}
\degree{2011--2017}{PhD}{Computational Commutative Algebra}{Somewhere}
\degree{1999--2002}{M.Sc.}{General Topology}{Somewhere}
\degree{1995--1999}{B.Sc.}{Pure Mathematics w/ minor in physics}{Somewhere}


\end{document}
```

You can compare the result of the code above and the result of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[5][in]{\years{#2}\textsc{#3} #1 \emph{#4}, \textsc{#5}\\}
\begin{document}

\section*{Degrees}
\degree[on]{2017--2018}{Postdoctoral Research}{Computational Mathematics}{Somewhere}
\degree{2011--2017}{PhD}{Computational Commutative Algebra}{Somewhere}
\degree{1999--2002}{M.Sc.}{General Topology}{Somewhere}
\degree{1995--1999}{B.Sc.}{Pure Mathematics w/ minor in physics}{Somewhere}


\end{document}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your both codes looks identical to me. Where is the difference?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the question... they should be different in having parskip in line 2.

Answer (score 5):

In your example you are missing one of the arguments of your \degree command: It has 5 mandatory arguments but are only giving 4.

Beside this, it is normally better not to issue `\marginnote` in vertical mode, when the paragraph hasn't started yet. Move the command behind the first word, or use e.g. `\leavevmode`. I would also end the `\degree` with `\par` and not `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote,parskip}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[6][in]{\leavevmode\years{#2}\textsc{#3} #1 \emph{#4}, #5, \textsc{#6}\par}
\begin{document}

\section*{Degrees}

\degree[on]{2017--2018}{Postdoctoral Research}{Computational Mathematics}{Somewhere}{}
\degree{2011--2017}{PhD}{Computational Commutative Algebra}{Somewhere}{}
\degree{1999--2002}{M.Sc.}{General Topology}{Somewhere}{}
\degree{1995--1999}{B.Sc.}{Pure Mathematics w/ minor in physics}{Somewhere}{}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question... and also removed the 6th argument in the command definition... *my question still exists* if you remove the parskip you will see the result will change to what I really dislike, _WHY?_

Comment: As I already wrote: use \leavevmode.

Comment: As I said... If you use \leavevmode at the beginning and \par at the end of the command you will still see the outputs are different when using parskip and not.

Comment: I used \leavevmode at the beginning and \\ at the end of the command... and found the results are same using or not using parskip except an extra blankspace after the section title, _say_ Degrees. this should have a little care for cure, too.

Comment: You have different dashes in your code. the first one is shorter.

Comment: Did you run the code? if so, didn't you note that the lines are not alligned?
(The hash is not a problem, I will fix that typo)

Comment: I did run my code and the lines are aligned, I show a screenshot in the answer.