# Bold text multiple paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, bold

What I want is to be able to do

```
\textbf{

paragraph 1

paragraph 2

}
```

but the compiler complains that I've put new paragraphs inside `\textbf{}`.

I had the same problem with `\textcolor` but this [How to colour multiple paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49910/how-to-colour-multiple-paragraphs) 
solved that perfectly. I'm looking for an equivalent solution for bold text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You cannot have paragraphs in the argument of `\textbf`. Use the `\bfseries` declaration instead. You can limit its scope by surrounding the text to be affected with braces, e.g. `{\bfseries paragraph 1 \par paragraph 2}`.