# Color some paragraphs in blue

Tags: color

I need to color some paragraphs of my article in blue. These paragraphs include texts and formulas. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `\color{blue}` (`color` or `xcolor` package)

Comment: Yeah, what @DavidCarlisle said. However, don't forget to have a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` around the paragraphs so that the color change does not propogate.  Also see [Environments for visually setting text apart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37245/4301) for other options to highlight paragraphs.

Comment: Can you see too at the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49910/how-to-colour-multiple-paragraphs.