# \phantom inside tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, tabularx

I tried to improve the alignment in the following table using a `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2.8cm} X}
    1/00\,--\,2/00 & text text \\
   \hphantom{0}1/00\,--\,2/00 & text text \\
   01/00\,--\,2/00  & text text \\
   10/00\,--\,11/00 & text text
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

but somehow this adds a lineskip in the cell containing the `\hphantom`:
[image: sample output]

Being fully aware that the error is on my side, and not in the `tabularx` package, my two questions are:

1. Can I make the `\hphantom` work somehow inside the the `tabularx`?
2. Even without the offending row containing the `\hphantom` I get an `Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide)`, which should not be there. What can I do to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Use `\leavevmode\hphantom{0}`

Comment: See last sentences here: [Function and usage of \leavevmode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode)

Comment: Use `\noindent` *before* you start the `tabularx`. The 15pt is the regular paragraph indent that `tabularx` is pushed to the right. Also, you could use `\mbox{}\hphantom{0}`.

Comment: @Werner Drat, that 15pt should have ring a bell...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your row is defined as a `\parbox`. The `\parbox` always starts in vertical mode. This can be shown by the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{8cm}{\ifvmode vmode \else hmode \fi}
\end{document}
```

That means a simple next box will continue the previous *vertical list* without switching modes. You need to start the paragraph explicitly in horizontal mode to use a box e.g. `\hphantom`. This is explained in the previous answer [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode). More information are given in the TeX Book:

> Simply saying `\hbox{...}` won’t work, since that box will just continue
>   the previous vertical list without switching modes. You need to start
>   the paragraph explicitly, and the straightforward way to do that is
>   to say `\indent\hbox{...}`. But suppose you want to define a macro that
>   expands to an `hbox`, where this macro is to be used in the midst of a
>   paragraph as well as at the beginning; then you don’t want to force
>   users to type `\indent` before calling your macro at the beginning of a
>   paragraph, nor do you want to say `\indent` in the macro itself (since
>   that might insert unwanted indentations). One solution to this more
>   general problem is to say `‘\␣\unskip\hbox{...}’`, since `\␣` makes the
>   mode horizontal while `\unskip` removes the unwanted space. Plain TEX
>   provides a `\leavevmode` macro, which solves this problem in what is
>   probably the most efficient way: `\leavevmode` is an abbreviation for
>   `‘\unhbox\voidbox’`, where `\voidbox` is a permanently empty box register.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\parbox{8cm}{\ifvmode vmode \else hmode \fi}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2.8cm} X}
    1/00\,--\,2/00 & text text \\
   \leavevmode\hphantom{0}1/00\,--\,2/00 & text text \\
   01/00\,--\,2/00  & text text \\
   10/00\,--\,11/00 & text text
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

As mentioned by Werner:  Use \noindent before you start the tabularx. The 15pt is the regular paragraph indent that tabularx is pushed to the right. This avoids the `15pt overfull \hbox`.

Answer (score 8):

Marco has given the correct way to use `\hphantom` in LaTeX but there shouldn't be any need to fake alignment with phantoms in an alignment structure like a tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r@{\,--\,}lp{2.8cm} X}
    1/00&2/00 & text text \\
   1/00&2/00 & text text \\
   01/00&2/00  & text text \\
   10/00&11/00 & text text
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the cooked down MWE looks like this. But in the real document there is other, quite different stuff in that column, and I would need to resort to `\multicolumn` and other tricks.

Comment: @mafp well that's OK you should accept Marco's then (I see you already have:-)

Answer (score 2):

Insert `noindent` ...but I do not know if it is good practice

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2.8cm} X}
    1/00\,--\,2/00 & text text \\
\noindent   \hphantom{0}1/00\,--\,2/00  & text text  \\ 
   01/00\,--\,2/00  & text text \\
   10/00\,--\,11/00 & text text
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `noindent` tells TeX explicitly to go into horizontal mode. So nearly equal to `leavevmode`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel just all I know is that it works.... and the truth is without understanding why! :)