# Number-Alignment with siunitx in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

Update... after a update to recent version of siunitx, everything is fine now. Thanks a lot @daleif and @crissov :-)

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
decimalsymbol=comma,
range-units = single,alsoload=synchem,separate-uncertainty
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \begin{tabular}{l
    S[table-format = 1.3(4),table-number-alignment=left]}
    \toprule
    Hello world & {some numbers}\\
    \midrule
    Hello world & 1,234\pm 5,678\\
    Hello world & 1,234\\
Hello world & 1,234\pm 5,678\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Results in some bad alignment for the line without uncertainty - see picture:
[image: bad alignment]

I've tried to get a left-aligned result with the `table-number-alignment=left` argument, but it didn't work out so far. Is there an option for aligning lines with numbers without uncertainity like numbers with, so the result is like

1,234 +/- 5,678

1,234

1,234 +/- 5,678

(decimalsymbols are vertical aligned)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which `siunitx` version are you using? In my version 2013/07/31 v2.5s, the alignment is as expected, the 2nd row 1234 is aligned with the other 1234.

Comment: Like @daleif, I can’t reproduce the result, getting instead what you desire. Anyways, [`\hphantom`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106578/phantom-inside-tabularx) might provide a hacky solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved with an update to the package