# Vfill after a table does not work

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table at the top and  would like to place the title at the page mid - or place it with vspace. But it doesn't work. Here is my code and my problem is on line 17 (the vfill do nothing).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XX|} \hline
    \textbf{Received:}           & \textbf{Approved:}  \\
                              & \textbf{Date:}      \\
                              & \textbf{Signature:} \\
\textbf{(for the instructor)} &
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\vfill %Why does this do nothing?

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\Large{{\itshape Course}\\}
{\fontsize{40}{48} \textsc{\textbf{Title}}}\\
\rule{7.5cm}{0.1cm}\\
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{large}
\textsc{%
University\\
Institution\\
\today\\
}%
\vspace{0.25cm}
\rule{3.75cm}{0.1cm}
\end{large}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vfill

Author \hfill E-mail

\end{document}
```

Kind regards and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Put `\null` or `\mbox{}` or `\leavevmode `just above the `\vfill` and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Here is a post why we need `\leavevmode`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22853/10898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table` creates a float. So in the main page, there is nothing at all before the `\vfill` so there is no need, LaTeX thinks, to fill it. (There is nothing to fill.) However, you presumably don't want a float here: you don't want the tabular to move. So don't put it in a `table`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XX|} \hline
\textbf{Received:}           & \textbf{Approved:}  \\
                          & \textbf{Date:}      \\
                          & \textbf{Signature:} \\
\textbf{(for the instructor)} &
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\vfill %Why does this do nothing?


\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\centering
{\Large\itshape Course\\}
{\fontsize{40}{48} \textsc{\textbf{Title}}}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.1cm}\\
\vspace{0.25cm}
\large
\textsc{%
University\\
Institution\\
\today\\
}%
\vspace{0.25cm}
\rule{3.75cm}{0.1cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vfill

Author \hfill E-mail

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular unfloated]