# changes package in table: spurious extra line in "p"-type column

Tags: tables, spacing, changes

When using the `changes` package in a table, I am experiencing spurious extra lines in the marked-up output for the columns defined as `p`-type (see example).

These extra lines disappear in the final version of the document. How can I get rid of these? (please note that in my actual table I do have the need to define the column width, and therefore use the `p`-type).

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}

\newcolumntype{a}{p{2.0cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|a|l|a|l|}
\cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-4}
Text& Text& Text& Text\\
\added{New text}& \added{New text}& \added{New text}& \added{New text}\\
\cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\leavevmode` to your new column type.

For more info about it, see [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode/22853).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\leavevmode}p{2.0cm}}% <-- \leavevmode added here

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|a|l|a|l|}
        \cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-4}
        Text& Text& Text& Text\\
        \added{New text}& \added{New text}& \added{New text}& \added{New text}\\
        \cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you CarLaTex! Can you please update your code to see where exactly should I put the `\leavevmode`?

Comment: @dontpanic Sorry, cut & paste error, I'll do it at once

Comment: @dontpanic Done, see the new column type definition :)