# \leavevmode@ifvmode undefined for xindy/texindy?

Tags: biblatex, luatex, imakeidx, xindy

I was getting `"The control sequence at the end of the top line"` referring to `\leavevmodeifvmode` for all my entries in an `.ind` file. Each entry of `\indexentry` in the `idx` file is translated to

```
 \item \emph  {{\textendash }\leavevmodeifvmode \kern .5em \textnormal  {something }, 11,22
```

in the `.ind` file.

Since I could not find any reference to leavevmodeifvmode I guess this relates to `leavevmode@ifvmode` which seems to be a new definition from 2018/12/01 [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode).

The related lines in preamble are:

```
\RequirePackage[texindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc,  name=title, title={Index: Titles}, columns=1, options=-M title  -C utf8 ]
```

I could fix the problem temporarily by doing something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{title.xdy}
        (require "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy")
        (require "texindy.xdy")


        \begin{theindex}

            \makeatletter
            \providecommand*\leavevmodeifvmode{\leavevmode@ifvmode}
            \makeatother
....
        \end{filecontents*}
```

However, I guess there is a problem with in translating `\indexterm`to the correct lines (whether by xindy or imakeidx ?). Is this a problem to wait for a bug fix or I wrote something wrong (sorry, not easy to make a MWE)

## edit

An MWE (I had to involve biblatex as the index is populated by biblatex, so now I think a suspect might be biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp, 
    autocite = superscript,
    indexing=true,
    backend=biber,
  sorting=none
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{title.xdy}
(require "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy")
(require "texindy.xdy")

(require "page-ranges.xdy")
(require "book-order.xdy")
(markup-index :open  "~n
\begin{theindex}
%   \makeatletter
%   \providecommand*\leavevmodeifvmode{\leavevmode@ifvmode}
%   \makeatother
    \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
        \textit{#1}
        \nopagebreak
    }
~n"
    :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)
\end{filecontents*}

\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section}%
\makeindex[intoc,  name=title, title={Index: Titles}, columns=1, options=-M title  -C utf8 ]


    \DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
        \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[title]}{{\textendash}\enspace\textnormal{#1}}}%


    \renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%

        \ifciteindex%
            {\indexnames{labelname}%
                \indexfield{indextitle}%
                \indexfield{maintitle}%      booktitle
                \indexfield{booktitle}%      booktitle
                }{}%
    }
    \renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
        \ifbibindex%
            {\indexnames{author}%
            \indexnames{editor}%
            \indexnames{editora}%
            \indexnames{editorb}%
            \indexnames{editorc}%
            \indexfield{indextitle}}%
            {}
    }



  \DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[]%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
      {}
      {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}




\begin{document}

For test \autocite{Knu86}.


\printindex[title]

\end{document}
```

Note: look at the title.ind at this line:

```
  \item m {}book\emph  {{\textendash }\leavevmodeifvmode \kern .5em \textnormal  {The T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\spacefactor \m {}book}}, 1
```

Comment: Can you please make a complete example?

Comment: @egreg, I added an MWE with some notes.

Comment: @egreg in the robustness branch it works. Frank will be pleased ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two commands robust. They break when going through the idx:

```
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\enspace
\robustify\TeX
```

(In a development version of latex they are already robust and your example compiles without problems).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.