# Scale text (\scalebox) in Plain TeX/XeTeX to make it narrower

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, scaling, scalebox

I've been looking up stuff and searching through the Internet for a few
hours now.  Basically, I need to do something like this, which I can do
in LaTeX with the `graphicx` package:

```
\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{NARROW}
```

**But!** I need to do it using *plain* TeX (XeTeX with PDF,
to be precise), pereferably with no packages.  What is the simplest,
most direct way to do it?  Does it have something to do with
`\setbox` and `\wd`?  I could only try:

```
\def\narrow#1{
  \setbox0\hbox{#1}
  \multiply\wd0 by 0.7
  \box0
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work, it errors out with
`` You can't use `\wd' after \multiply. ``

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To make your approach you'd need `\wd0=0.7\wd0` instead. However this will only change the width of the box, but the characters therein will not change, so some will protrude outside the box. You need driver-specific code to do that. You can load `graphicx` in Plain with `\input graphicx.tex`.

Comment: Thank you!  I've updated the question to include the fact that I'm using XeTeX with PDF output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dgoodmaniii's answer already shows you why your code didn't work, and how to make it work. However TeX itself doesn't know how to “scale” things. You can only change the dimensions of boxes, but the characters inside them remain untouched. To have the same scaling as `\scalebox` you need driver-specific code, which will be different from one engine to the other.

Since you use XeTeX, here's the `\scalebox` code that I <s>stole</s> adapted from `graphics.sty` and `dvipdfmx.def`. The code from `graphics.sty` contains the warpper macro `\scalebox`, which uses `\Gscale@start` and `\Gscale@end`. These two macros put the `\special`s which will do the scaling (not that due to my lazyness, the second argument of `\scalebox` is no longer optional):

> [image]

```
\catcode`\@=11
\long\def\scalebox#1#2#3{%
  \leavevmode
  \def\Gscale@x{#1}\def\Gscale@y{#2}%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{{#3}}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\Gscale@start\rlap{\copy\z@}\Gscale@end}%
  \ifdim#2\p@<\z@
    \ht\tw@-#2\dp\z@
    \dp\tw@-#2\ht\z@
  \else
    \ht\tw@#2\ht\z@
    \dp\tw@#2\dp\z@
  \fi
  \ifdim#1\p@<\z@
    \hbox to-#1\wd\z@{\kern-#1\wd\z@\box\tw@\hss}%
  \else
    \hbox to#1\wd\z@{\box\tw@\kern#1\wd\z@\hss}%
  \fi}
\def\GPT@space{ }
\def\Gscale@start{%
  \special{pdf:btrans}%
  \special{x:scale \Gscale@x\GPT@space\Gscale@y}}
\def\Gscale@end{\special{pdf:etrans}}
\catcode`\@=12

\scalebox{0.7}{1.0}{NARROW}\par
\scalebox{1.0}{1.0}{NARROW}\par
\scalebox{1.3}{1.0}{NARROW}\par

\bye
```

Of course, just loading `graphicx.tex` is much easier (and engine independent):

```
\input graphicx.tex

\scalebox{0.7}[1.0]{NARROW}\par
\scalebox{1.0}{NARROW}\par
\scalebox{1.3}[1.0]{NARROW}\par

\bye
```

Comment: I've simplified your answer and posted my current stuff [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518035/173564), but I am going to accept your answer as correct, because it does what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ainar-G Well, yes, the code can certainly be simplified. The version from `graphics` takes into account the possibility of negative scaling factors, which in your case (apparently fixed `0.7`) is not a problem, so the code can be shortened. Personally I'd prefer something that works in more general cases, but that's just _my_ preference :-) (P.S.: I'd add `\leavevmode` to the beginning of your code. Try `\narrow{Hello}\par Hello\par` to see the problem)

Comment: I see now.  Edited my answer.  Thanks again!

For anyone reading, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22853/173564) on why you need `\leavevmode`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `\wd` is basically an operator; you give it the box you want the width of.  Also keep in mind that `\multiply` doesn't work with floating-point numbers, only integers; so if you want to multiply by something like 0.7, you'll have to multiply by 7 and then divide by 10.

Assuming that the full length is `\hsize`, and you want a box 0.7 times `\hsize`:

```
\hbox to\hsize{This box will be the full width}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox\hbox to\hsize{\hfil}
\newdimen\mywidth\mywidth=\wd\mybox
\multiply\mywidth by7
\divide\mywidth by10
\hbox to\mywidth{This box will be the right width}
\bye
```

The first line is purely for demonstrative purposes, to show the full length of the line.  Then we declare a new box, `\mybox`, and make sure that its width is also equal to `\hsize` by assigning to it an empty `\hbox` of that width.  Then we declare a new `dimen`, `\mywidth`, and set it equal to the width of `\mybox`.  Then we multiply `\mywidth` by 7 and divide it by 10, which is the equivalent of multiplying by 0.7.  Finally, we put some text in a box of `\mywidth`, which, as you can see, if 70% the width of the original box.

You can, of course, wrap this in a macro:

```
\hbox to\hsize{This box will be the full width}

\newbox\mybox
\newdimen\mywidth
\def\width#1#2#3#4{%
    \setbox\mybox\hbox to#1{\hfil}
    \mywidth=\wd\mybox
    \multiply\mywidth by#2
    \divide\mywidth by#3
    \hbox to\mywidth{#4}
}%

\width{\hsize}{7}{10}{This box will be the short width}
\width{\hsize}{8}{10}{This box will be the short width}
\width{\hsize}{4}{10}{This box will be the short width}
\bye
```

That will produce the following:

[image]

If you need the text to wrap, wrap the `#4` in a `\hbox` and `\vbox` and change the `\hsize` inside it:

```
\newbox\mybox
\newdimen\mywidth
\def\width#1#2#3#4{%
    \setbox\mybox\hbox to#1{\hfil}
    \mywidth=\wd\mybox
    \multiply\mywidth by#2
    \divide\mywidth by#3
    \hbox to\mywidth{%
        \hfil%
        \vbox{%
            \hsize=\mywidth
            #4
        }%
        \hfil%
    }
}%
```

Hope that answers your need.

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified @phelype-oleinik's example as much as I could, and
I came up with this:

```tex
\def\narrow#1{%
  % Enter horizonal mode to make sure we don't bork up the start of the
  % paragraph.
  \leavevmode%
  % Set the scale factors.
  \def\ScaleX{0.7}%
  \def\ScaleY{1.0}%
  % Set box zero to the box with the text as is, without scaling, to get
  % the width of this box.  Not sure if that can be done without \setbox.
  \setbox 0 \hbox{#1}%
  \def\NewWidth{\ScaleX \wd 0}%
  % The next box will overfull, but that's okay, as long as it's within
  % the new width.
  \hfuzz = \NewWidth%
  % Create a horizontal box with the new width containing the scaled
  % text.
  \hbox to \NewWidth {%
    \special{pdf:btrans}%
    % x:scale requires that the two numbers are separated by a space.
    \special{x:scale \ScaleX\space\ScaleY}%
    #1%
    \special{pdf:etrans}%
  }%
}
```

This works for me, but if you see any potential issues, please let me
know.

Comment: If you want to make it simpler you can also use `#1\hss` instead of setting `\hfuzz` (seems simpler to me, at least :-). Also you don't need to define `\NewWidth`, you can simply `\hbox to \ScaleX \wd 0{`, which save you from doing one definition. The readability of the code is debatable, though ;-)